# How to build one docker image for multiple projects?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

In my project I am using .net core 2.2 , recently I am using additional class library inside my project.
When I am trying to build my image it can not found my dll.

My docker file looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LibvirtManagement.dll"]
```

I am getting error like this:

```
 The project file "/JenkinsService/JenkinsService.csproj" was not found. 
 [/app/LibvirtManagement.sln]
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o out' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty straightforward, you're missing `JenkinsService.csproj` and other files from this project in docker container where you build it. You need to copy these files as well.

If you're using Visual Studio the easiest way to do it is to right-click executable project file (`LibvirtManagement` in your case) and then select `Add -> Docker Support...`. It will auto-generate correct `Dockerfile` for you

EDIT: this is what this tool created for me:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["LibvirtManagement/LibvirtManagement.csproj", "LibvirtManagement/"]
COPY ["JenkinsService/JenkinsService.csproj", "JenkinsService/"]
RUN dotnet restore "LibvirtManagement/LibvirtManagement.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/LibvirtManagement"
RUN dotnet build "LibvirtManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "LibvirtManagement.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LibvirtManagement.dll"]
```

Comment: I got this error  `COPY ["LibvirtManagement/LibvirtManagement.csproj", "LibvirtManagement/"]COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder036005313/LibvirtManagement/LibvirtManagement.csproj: no such file or directory`  My dll inside my project and not in gitlab in my case I don't know it makes sense or not. Cause I don't want to publish code here